# python,find Specified word in large text file and return that lines?

Tags: python-3.x

i have large text file.i want to find Specified word on that file and i want to  know the line of that word in file.(maybe the word Repeated several time, i want to know all lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    allLines = f.readlines()
    for lineNumber in range(len(allLines)):
        if "word" in allLines[lineNumber]:
            print("Match in line {0}".format(lineNumber))
```